# Maximum amps from a switching voltage regulator

Tags: power, power-electronics, power-engineering, regulations, current

Looking at a part like this
LM2596

It is rated for 3Amps with a voltage range from 3.3-12 volts.

Does that mean that this voltage regulator will only output a maximum of 3amps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an oversimplification.

From the data sheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf there are two relevant features, internal over-temperature protection and a maximum current limiter (Typical value 4.5A, minimum 3.6A).

The bottom line is that trying to get more than 3A *continuous* current from the regulator will probably not end well.